15 over/down Treble/Bass Clef in Finale26 MakeMusic
I'm on Finale 26 MakeMusic and I'd like to create a Treble/Bass Clef with 15 over/down the clef. For example if Key7 is Octave Bass Clef I'd like to change the 8 into 15, obtaining a Double-Octave Bass Clef, and so on for other Clefs.
Is it possible?
Thank you in advanced.

Can you edit to say a bit about why? I wonder whether this is just about getting a certain audio output, or whether this will be read by actual humans. I'm always a bit puzzled when people try to use notation as a tool to get the MIDI output they want, rather than just editing a piano roll or other methods...

I don't understand your comment... . In my Piano works, sometimes, I use 0-octave, i. e. the sub-contra-bass octave, and also the highest octave, the 7th of the normal pianos or the 8th one of the Stuart&Sons pianos. And in my Organ works, sometimes, I use the most high Organ notes, from C9 to G9.

So this is for humans to read? Often there are questions that are simply focused on getting audio out of the software. I was wondering why you're using clefs rather than 8va markings; see https://music.stackexchange.com/q/123537/78419

Also, see https://www.scoringnotes.com/tips/create-a-custom-clef-in-finale/

You should follow https://www.scoringnotes.com/tips/create-a-custom-clef-in-finale/ the Bravura font that they use in that tutorial has a symbol for a bass clef 2 octaves below (symbol 342).
